# Understanding the "module" (or extension)

Tags: module, magento-1, extensions, magento-connect-manager

I've been able to study **5 Magento shops** in the last weeks. And I've noticed a mess in module management.

I've seen 2 places where the `modules/extensions` appear:

- MagentoConnect page: where you can see the module name, description, version and you are able to uninstall or upgrade
- `/app/etc/modules` directory: where the main `XML` of the module appear

**My questions about modules:**

1) Why do I see some modules appearing in **`"etc"`** directory, but they don't appear in Magento Connect page ?

2) In that cases, how can I uninstall a module?

3) And how can I know which files are related with that module ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Why do I see some modules appearing in "etc" directory, but they
   don't appear in MagentoConnect page ?

   A Magento Connect will contain Modules which packaged using standard
   packages of magento extension.

   Magento Connect doesn't know anything about the custom Modules that
   have been installed into your system without proper packaging.
2. In that cases, how can I uninstall a module?

   You can simply remove files or disable it from app/etc/modules
3. And how can I know which files are related with that module ?

   You can check everything from xml files.

   app/etc/modules/Namespace_Module.xml

which would be something like below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Namespace_Module>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>community</codePool>
            </Namespace_Module>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

You can find codepool from here that can be local/commuinty

Now in that codepool there will be config.xml for your module.

```
app/code/{{codepool}}/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml
```

And you can all classes define here as well as front and back layout if any exits so you can also check related tempalte and css , js files

Answer (score 1):

1. The module are installed from **MagentoConnect page** that will be shown in 
   MagentoConnect page. but all the module are listed in `etc/modules/` folder. For those modules are not listed these are manual. Pasted in main directory on magento folder the get installed.
2. MagentoConnect For that it is easy to unistall there is option for that. But the manual you have to remove every file related to module. For `etc/modules` you can disabled the extension by open the file in editor and make `true` to `false`
3. Mostly the module name are `Spacename_Modulename.xml` you will get the idea of that when you see the module name.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extend/Modify Any features in Magento then you need to crate a module.For publish your module publicly on [Magento connect](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/) you need to System > Magento Connect > Package Extensions you can pack your module here.You can find all modules under this app/etc/modules folder. If you want to disable any module.

e.g. open any file from here ( app/etc/modules) you will see codes something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Arun_Athletes>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Arun_Athletes>
  </modules>
</config>
```

For disable it completelly just change it from `<active>true</active>` to `<active>false</active>`

Hope this will help you.